# Getting the name of a w3c Document

Tags: java, xml, w3c

Is this possible? For example, if I run the jSoup Code:

```
Document source = Jsoup.connect("http://www.xmlFile.com/file.xml").get();
// Convert the Jsoup object to a w3c Document object with Apache.
return DOMBuilder.jsoup2DOM(source);
```

I now have a `w3c Document` object. Is there any way of getting `file.xml` from that object? I've not found anything online that informs me eitherway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method `Document` called `getDocumentUri()` that might do what you want.  It seems to depend on what way the Document was created whether the Uri is set to something or `null`.  I don't know how JSoup creates the documents, so your mileage may vary.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#getDocumentURI()

If JSoup doesn't set it, you could call `setDocumentUri()` manually in your method, and then use `getDocumentUri()` where you needed it?

Comment: I worked out a nicer solution than parsing the URI, but this answers the question perfectly. :)